# Looking for a webmail focussed on privacy

Tags: open-source, web-apps, email, web-services

Currently I'm still using Google Mail and I want to move from it. So I'm looking for a webmail with the following features:

- Must be fully accessible per web
- import other email adresses (e.g. from my own server)
- no data crawling, for e.g. ads
- open source

Optional features (no must-have) would be:

- security-stuff, like encrypted mails
- Android app

For now I've looked into two services:

- ProtonMail: seems like the perfect one! But to read external email adresses one must pay and I don't want to pay just for checking out if it works, as I may have to change mail DNS, which I don't have access to.
- OpenMailBox: Looks nice, but registration isn't open anymore and as I heard they're considering taking down the service.

Comment: Not tried myself, but mailbox.org offers a free 30 day trial. Apart from which, I'm not sure if this is a valid question for SR ("SaaS") or falls into the category "hosting requests" ;)

Comment: Hey, they speak my language! But I guess it's closed source.. :/

Comment: Wrong guess, see [Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mailbox.org): *Als Grundlage der Webmail-Oberfläche nutzt mailbox.org die freie Software OX App Suite des Unternehmens [Open-Xchange](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open-Xchange).* (English: "Base of the webmail UI is the fee Software OX App Suite of Open-Xchange"; there's no English Wikipedia page currently). Open-Xchange is using GPLv2 / CC BY-NC, and thus open source.